# Centering a fixed-width div with CSS by using margin:0 auto; not effective

Tags: css, html, centering

I was able to figure this out before, and I remember doing essentially this, but for some reason it doesn't work now. I have a middle column for a website that needs to be centered ([like so](http://h.dropcanvas.com/yzebt/Screen%20Shot%202011-12-25%20at%207.09.30%20PM.png)), but the normal margin:0 auto; doesn't work, yielding instead [this](http://h.dropcanvas.com/yzebt/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-16%20at%208.33.31%20PM.png) (the CSS formatting for the link items for the navbar also doesn't work, but that is a different problem entirely). My CSS for the main column and the parent is:

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    background:url(images/BGTop.png) repeat-x;
}
div#main {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 1px;
    size:auto 730px;
    background:url(images/mainbg.png) repeat-y;
}
```

You'll notice that the BG doesn't work, either. Is this the same problem? Why isn't any of the CSS working (except, I presume, the padding on `#main`)? The HTML doesn't appear to be the problem:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="#">home</a></li>
        <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="#">bingo</a></li>
        ...
        <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" href="#">music</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You DO have the div, with id="main" correct?

Comment: @BryanMoyles Yeah, sorry, I put the HTML in there just now.

Comment: You need to add a width to #main

Answer (score 5):

Where did you get the `size` property from? You should be using `width: 730px`. The `size` line is being thrown away because it's invalid. The width is still being calculated as `auto`.

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6pU/) (You'll have to resize the box enough to see it centering.)

---

If you're curious, the `size` property is used for paged media. I don't know much about it, but it does not do what you think it does. It's meant to set the actual (real life) size of the page, most commonly in inches, such as `size: 8.5" 11"` (the default size of a piece of paper).